# How to Populate Input Text Field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I tried to collect data from JSON to fill out related Input Text Field after matching results, but it's not working.

How can I get populate the input text field from the JSON?

**JS Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var filter = document.getElementById('zipcode');
var JSONtbl = [
  {"zipcode":01702,"address":"334 CONCORD ST","County":"MIDDLESEX"},
  {"zipcode":02482,"address":"27 Atwood St","County":"NORFOLK"},
  {"zipcode":02459,"address":"189 Cypress St","County":"MIDDLESEX"}
      ];
filter.onkeyup = function() {
    var zipcodeToSearch = filter.value;
    var n = zipcodeToSearch.length;
    if (n < 5) {
     document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementById("County").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < JSONtbl.length; i++) {
         if (JSONtbl[i].zipcode == zipcodeToSearch) {
          document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = JSONtbl[i].address;
          document.getElementById("County").innerHTML = JSONtbl[i].County;
             }
        }
        if (document.getElementById("address").innerHTML == "") {
            alert("ZipCode Out Of Area")
        }
    }
};
});
```

```css
div {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
<div><input type="text" id="zipcode"/></div>
<div><input type="text" id="address" disabled="disabled"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="County" disabled="disabled"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use value instead of innerHTML

Comment: thanks for helping

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please upvote it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two mistakes in your code.

**First:** Input does't have innerHTML but value.
**Second** You are assigning integer to zipcode starting with zero. Rather you need a string type because value returned by input will be a string.

use this code

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('zipcode');
var JSONtbl = [
  {"zipcode":"01702","address":"334 CONCORD ST","County":"MIDDLESEX"},
  {"zipcode":"02482","address":"27 Atwood St","County":"NORFOLK"},
  {"zipcode":"02459","address":"189 Cypress St","County":"MIDDLESEX"}
      ];
filter.onkeyup = function() {
    var zipcodeToSearch = filter.value;
    var n = zipcodeToSearch.length;
    if (n < 5) {
     document.getElementById("address").value = "";
     document.getElementById("County").value = "";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < JSONtbl.length; i++) {
            
         if (JSONtbl[i].zipcode == zipcodeToSearch) {
           
          document.getElementById("address").value = JSONtbl[i].address;
          document.getElementById("County").value = JSONtbl[i].County;
             }
        }
        if (document.getElementById("address").value == "") {
            alert("ZipCode Out Of Area")
        }
    }
};
```

```css
div {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<div><input type="text" id="zipcode"/></div>
<div><input type="text" id="address" disabled="disabled"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="County" disabled="disabled"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input elements do not have a inner html property. Rather they have a `value` property. So this:

```
document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = JSONtbl[i].address;
document.getElementById("County").innerHTML = JSONtbl[i].County;
```

should be :

```
document.getElementById("address").value = JSONtbl[i].address;
document.getElementById("County").value = JSONtbl[i].County;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var filter = document.getElementById('zipcode');
        var JSONtbl = [
                {"zipcode":"01702","address":"334 CONCORD ST","County":"MIDDLESEX"},
                {"zipcode":"02482","address":"27 Atwood St","County":"NORFOLK"},
                {"zipcode":"02459","address":"189 Cypress St","County":"MIDDLESEX"}
                 ];
        filter.onkeyup = function() {
            var zipcodeToSearch = filter.value;
            var n = zipcodeToSearch.length;
            if (n < 5) {
                document.getElementById("address").value = "";
                document.getElementById("County").value = "";
            } else {

                for (var i = 0; i < JSONtbl.length; i++) {

                    if (JSONtbl[i].zipcode == zipcodeToSearch) {

                        document.getElementById("address").value = JSONtbl[i].address;
                        document.getElementById("County").value = JSONtbl[i].County;
                     }
                }
                if (document.getElementById("address").value == "") {
                    alert("ZipCode Out Of Area")
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can do like this:

```
$('#Input_id').val(JsonValue);
```